# issue with position:fixed

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code for a table structure where I try to freeze it's header. I have fixed the header using position:fixed . While making so the table header losses it's column width and there is a misalignment between thead and tbody column widths .. Can any one tell how to avoid this situation ??

```
<div class="outer_div"  style=" width: 1316px;height: 324px;overflow: auto;"> 
<table  class="scrollTable" id="invoiceMeasurement_table"
style="width: 1316pxfloat: left;float: left;width: 1300px;table-layout: fixed;" >   
<thead 
<tr style="position: fixed;margin-top: -10%;width: 1316px;">
<th style="width:75px">Col1</th>
<th style="width:75px">Col2</th>
<th style="width:75px">Col3</th>
<th style="width:91px">Col4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody >
</tbody>/*tbody is getting generated dynamically */
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: The header gets fixed if I use                                        <tr style="position:relative ;width:1300px;">,but if I use like this the header moves while the body scrolls.

Comment: can you please explain what you exactly are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @JamieM23 I need to freeze the header for my table of the above said format

Answer (score 0):

You use this code in head tag and remove style float

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
   <style type="text/css">
     #fixedHeader{
        position:relative !important;
     }
   </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: <!--[if IE 8]>
   <style type="text/css">
     #fixedHeader{
        position:relative !important;
     }
   </style>
<![endif]-->

Comment: tied this too with no luck,                                         The header gets fixed if I use <tr style="position:relative ;width:1300px;">,but if I use like this the header moves while the body scrolls.

Comment: you use this code and remove all inner style  #fixedHeader{ position:relative !important; }

Comment: still not working,the table structure which I am using is given below..Could u pls tell me how to freeze the header for this table ?

Comment: '<div class="outer_div" class="tableContainer" > 
<table  class="scrollTable" id="invoiceMeasurement_table" > 
<thead class="fixedHeader" >
<tr >
<th style="width:75px">Col1</th>
<th style="width:75px">Col2</th>
<th style="width:75px">Col3</th>
<th style="width:91px">Col4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>/*tbody is getting generated dynamically */
<tfoot id="table_footer">
<tr id="t-footer" style="font-weight:bold">
<th style="width:75px"></th>
<th style="width:75px"></th>
<th style="width:75px"></th>
<th style="width:91px"></th>
</tr>
</tfoot> 
</table>
</div>'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17999/discussion-between-ajith-and-saeed-py)

Comment: I have fixed the header using position:fixed . While making so the table header losses it's column width and there is a misalignment between thead and tbody column  widths .. Can any one tell how to avoid this situation ??

Comment: delete th and write td instead of th